# Track User with Closed App (Xamarin.Forms) - 2021

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, geolocation

I'm developing an App for protection purpose using Xamarin.Forms.

I'm stuck in finding a way to track user position when the app is closed (completely closed) in iOS and Android.

I saw people suggesting using foreground services, others job scheduling, but none of them worked properly. Most things I read are deprecated.

Can anyone give me an idea? I'll be VERY grateful.

Btw: I don't need to know the exact position all the time. Just in some circumstances, like a terrorist atack, I would need to know the high precision location of user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Xamarin.Essentials** which offer **Geolocation class** that provides APIs to retrieve the device's current geolocation coordinates.

To get location, you can use code like:

```
  CancellationTokenSource cts;

async Task GetCurrentLocation()
{
    try
    {
        var request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Medium, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(request, cts.Token);

        if (location != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Latitude: {location.Latitude}, Longitude: {location.Longitude}, Altitude: {location.Altitude}");
        }
    }
    catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fnsEx)
    {
        // Handle not supported on device exception
    }
    catch (FeatureNotEnabledException fneEx)
    {
        // Handle not enabled on device exception
    }
    catch (PermissionException pEx)
    {
        // Handle permission exception
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Unable to get location
    }
}
```

For more information, you can refer to this [Essentials.Geolocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/geolocation?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android)

Comment: Hi Adrain. I appreciate your answer but the problem is: How to call the geolocation service to get the geoposition and send it to the server with the app closed.

Comment: I see, you can see this document which is about job dispatcher https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/firebase-job-dispatcher